# Drawable layout on listview with ArrayAdapter

Tags: eclipse, listview, drawable, android-arrayadapter

How can I set one drawable in my layout to use listview?
this is my code and funcion normally but i can't click on item:

```
public class ListMobileActivity extends Activity {

static final String[] Ristoranti = new String[] { "Osteria Mingot", "Cecchini", "Barrique", "Mediterraneo"};

ListView listView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_mobile, R.id.label, Ristoranti);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I extends Activity I can set my drawable, if I extends ListActivity I can Click on the Item but the drawable appear in every item

```
protected void onItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)  {

    //get selected items
//  String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    //Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: I've solved with extends ListActivity and         listView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable));